# Return a struct from a mapping in test truffle

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing, tokens

I want the information stored in each struct inside the mapping.

This is my struct:

```
struct BurnApply {
    address applicant;
    uint amount;
    string btcAddress;
    uint8 flag; 
    uint password;
}
```

These are the counter(to the mapping) and the mapping:

```
uint numRequest; //zero initialize value
mapping(uint => BurnApply) burnProcesses;
```

I want to obtain the values of each request inside the struct. For instance,burnProcesses[1] contain the request number 1 with all the information. How I have to call to the mapping in truffle? Because I´ve tried several ways in order to achieve that but without success. This is urgent... This is the error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
```

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: i think you need to return it in bytes.

Comment: @ReiDien in truffle test? inside the test you have to use javascript...another thing is create your own getter function inside the smartcontract code in solidity. But, there is incompatibility converting variables in different types!!!

Comment: @Jorge Can you put the code of the test you are using?

Comment: @Jorge Having same issue. Did you get it resolved?

Comment: @Ismael I´ve tried several ways of calling instance.burnProcesses.call(1), instance.burnProcesses.call({from: 1}), instance.burnProcesses(1).call (I know that this last is incorrect but just for try)...also I´ve kept away var n = 1; and then try to call using n. but the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

you can test your code using

```
const instance= await yourcontract.new();

const result1=await instance.BurnApply.call(i);//set your i
```

then

access the struct attributes using

```
console.log(result1[i]); //i=0 ...
```

Comment: Any idea on how to do this in solidity tests?

Answer (score 2):

This contracts works for me. To access a member you have to declare it public (the compiler will create a getter automatically).

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Foo {
  struct BurnApply {
    address applicant;
    uint amount;
    string btcAddress;
    uint8 flag; 
    uint password;
  }

  mapping(uint => BurnApply) public burnProcesses;
}
```

Now you can call from javascript

```
const data = await fooInstance.burnProcesses.call(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll first have to `await contract.callThatReturnsTheStruct` and then access the desired property.

This does answer a 3 and a half  year old question. With solc > 0.8.0 you can do something like this:

`(await contract.mappingAttribute(key)).structAttribute` to get the attribute of a struct that is in a mapping

Answer (score 0):

Call `instance.burnProcesses.call(1)` - you'll get a Promise returned with the item at that uint in the mapping, if it exists.